# Linkify (plain url to link) based on windowSize

Tags: jquery

this is what i would like to do

1. when window size is < 1000, change any plain text url to a clickable one
2. when window size is > 1000, change any plain text url to a clickable one, replaced by the word "Link".

I had a go but it seems to be failing somewhere!

Anyone can shed some light?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
   <script>$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();
        if (windowSize < 1000) {
          $('div').each(function(){ $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a> ') ); });
        } //make plain text url clickable
        else if (windowSize < 1000) {
          $('div').each(function(){ $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a href="Link">Link</a> ') ); });
        } //convert plain text to clickable word "Link"

    }
    checkWidth();
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
    $(window).onload(checkWidth);
});
  </script>  
</head>  
<body>
  <div>https://www.google.com/</div>
  <div>https://www.yahoo.com/</div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<a href="Link">` shouldn't that also be `$1` as you only want to change the text and not the href

Comment: It looks like both your conditions in the if else if statements are the same `<1000`.  I think the first one should be `>1000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice solution from @jakecigar in the jquery forums

HTML:

```
<div>https://www.google.com/</div>
<div>https://www.yahoo.com/</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .abbr {
   font-size:0;
    text-decoration:none;
  }
  .abbr:after {
    display: inline;
    font-size:16px;
    content: "link";
    color:black;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a class=abbr href="$1">$1</a> '));
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
function checkWidth() {
        var windowSize = $(window).width();
        if (windowSize > 1000) {
          $('div').each(function(){
   var div = $(this).html();
   var link = $(this).find('a');
   var linkText = $(this).find('a').html();
   if(link.length === 0) {
    $(this).html(div.replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a> '));
   } else {
    $(this).find('a')[0].innerHTML = $(this).find('a')[0].href;
   }  
    });
        } //make plain text url clickable
        else if (windowSize < 1000) {
   $('div').each(function(){
    var div = $(this).html();
    var link = $(this).find('a');
    var linkText = $(this).find('a').html();
    if(link.length === 0) {
     $(this).html(div.replace(/((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w?=&.\/-;#~%-]+(?![\w\s?&.\/;#~%"=-]*>))/g, '<a href="$1">Link</a> '));
    } else {
     $(this).find('a')[0].innerHTML = 'Link';
    } 
   })
  }//convert plain text to clickable word "Link"
  
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        checkWidth();
    });
 //$(window).onload(checkWidth);
 $(window).resize(function(){checkWidth();});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
 
</head>  
<body>
  <div>https://www.google.com/</div>
  <div>https://www.yahoo.com/</div> 
  </body>
</html>
```